# kpathsea / tinytex problem when Windows profile includes non-ASCII characters

Tags: r, bookdown, tinytex

I am trying to use Rstudio, bookdown and tinytex to generate a pdf.
The book builds to a gitbook (Rstudio -> Build -> Build Book -> bookdown::gitbook) with no problems.
But when I try to generate a pdf (Rstudio -> Build -> Build Book -> bookdown::pdf_book) I get a message:

> LaTeX failed to compile _main.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See _main.log for more info.

In the _main.log I read:

> ! kpathsea: Running mktexfmt xelatex.fmt
>
> The command name is C:\Users\B?a?ej\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\windows\mktexfmt
> warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: C:/Users/B?a?ej/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/windows;C:/Users/B?a?ej/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/windows/share/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/B?a?ej/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/windows/share/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/B?a?ej/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/windows/share/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/B?a?ej/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/windows/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/B?a?ej/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/windows/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/B?a?ej/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/windows/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/B?a?ej/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin;C:/Users/B?a?ej/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/share/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/B?a?ej/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/share/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/B?a?ej/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/share/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/B?a?ej/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/B?a?ej/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/B?a?ej/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/B?a?ej/AppData/Roaming/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/B?a?ej/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX;C:/Users/B?a?ej/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/share/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/B?a?ej/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/share/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/B?a?ej/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/share/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/B?a?ej/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/B?a?ej/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/B?a?ej/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf/web2c.
> ...?ażej\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:941: ...?ażej\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:864: no appropriate script or program found: fmtutil
> Running the command C:\Users\B?a?ej\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\windows\fmtutil-user.exe

I looked for texmf.cnf and I can find it in C:\Users\Błażej\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX and C:\Users\Błażej\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\texmf-dist\web2c.

Which indicates for me that there is a problem somewhere between kpathsea and my user name, which is "Błażej", not "B?a?ej". It includes non-ASCII characters and I cannot change it.

Is there a way for me to build my book without changing my user name?

I tried to https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging, but similar kpathsea problems appear when I try to reinstall things.

I looked for a similar problem on the Web, but cannot find any answer.